# Storing Calculated Values into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, math

In my program, the equation is solved for y given a range of x values. How do I then store those values into y and print them out as the array. I thought I was supposed to use the index method but I have an error. 
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "]", VariableDeclaratorId expected after 
     this token
    - y cannot be resolved to a type

What do I need to modify?

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Standard {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double exponent,  x, pi, e, sqrtpart;
        double[] y;
        pi = 3.14159;
        e = 2.71828;
        x = -2.0;
        int count = 0;

        while (count < 20)
        {
        exponent = - ((x*x)/(2));

        sqrtpart = Math.sqrt(2*pi);

        y[] = (Math.pow(e,exponent))/sqrtpart;
        System.out.println(y[index]);

        x = x + 0.2;
        count++;
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you show your error. "but I have an error" doesn't give us much to go on, does it?

Comment: There's also an `index cannot be resolved to a variable` error on line 20.

Comment: Ok thank you everyone. This program is supposed to calculate normal distribution values but the numbers don't seem right? I went through my logic though twice and I couldn't find anything wrong. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
double[] y;
```

into

```
double[] y = new double[20];
```

And

```
    y[] = (Math.pow(e,exponent))/sqrtpart;
    System.out.println(y[index]);
```

into

```
    y[count] = (Math.pow(e,exponent))/sqrtpart;
    System.out.println(y[count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not put values into the `y array` as presently it does not have any size.

Try `double y [] = new double [20];`

Also

```
System.out.println(y[index]);
```

should be

```
System.out.println(y[count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize y

Put this outside the while loop

```
y = new double[<size of your array>];
```

Then you can use the index method

```
y[index] = (Math.pow(e,exponent))/sqrtpart;
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers help you fix the compiler problems. But there are other things you should consider:

1. You are calculating 1/sqrt(2*pi) in every single iteration in the while loop. This is not good from a performance point of view since this calculation will never change. So it is better to pull this calculation out of the while loop.
2. You don't need to define your own pi and e. Just use the static ones in the Math class: Math.PI, Math.E
3. You have hard-coded values in your code for the size of the array and the increments. That makes your code fragile. You could change one number and miss another.

So consider the following:

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Standard {

    static int size = 20;
    static double width = 4.0;
    static double increments = width/size; 

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        double exponent, x, sqrtpart;

        double[] y = new double[size];

        x = - (width / 2);

        sqrtpart = Math.sqrt(2* Math.PI);

        int count = 0;
        while (count < size)
        {
            exponent = - ((x*x)/(2));

            y[count] = (Math.pow(Math.E,exponent))/sqrtpart;

            System.out.println(y[count]);

            x = x + increments;

            count++;
        }
    }
}
```